# Rails 5 - How to strip tags from string in rails (NOT in/for html)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strip-tags

I need to strip tags from user input before saving into DB

I'm well aware of strip_tags method but it also html escapes string, as well as all other recommended methods:

```
Rails::Html::FullSanitizer.new.sanitize '&'
 => "&amp;" 
Rails::Html::WhiteListSanitizer.new.sanitize('&', tags: [])
 => "&amp;" 
ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags "&"
 => "&amp;"
```

The string I want to sanitize is NOT to be escaped, it's getting exported via API, used in files etc. it's NOT only outputted via HTML (where also in cases like `link_to ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags("&")` - link_to is double escaping string so you'll get link to `&amp;` in the frontend )

As a monkey patch I've wrapped strip_tags into `CGI.unescapeHTML` to get more or less expected result but want to find some straight solution (I'm also afraid what else can strip_tags do and there are too many moving parts for that small functionality - more stuff that can go wrong or become broken)

Real world example:
`JPMorgan Chase & Co` should become `JPMorgan Chase & Co` after removing tags

`test<script>alert('hacked!');</script>&test` should become `test&test` after stripping tags

And also string:

```
"test &#x3C;script&#x3E;alert(&#x27;hacked!&#x27;)&#x3C;/script&#x3E;"
```

Should still be

```
"test &#x3C;script&#x3E;alert(&#x27;hacked!&#x27;)&#x3C;/script&#x3E;"
```

After stripping HTMLs

With alternative solutions that I've found or that was proposed:

```
> Nokogiri::HTML("test &#x3C;script&#x3E;alert(&#x27;hacked!&#x27;)&#x3C;/script&#x3E;").text
 => "test <script>alert('hacked!')</script>"

> Loofah.fragment("test &#x3C;script&#x3E;alert(&#x27;hacked!&#x27;)&#x3C;/script&#x3E;").text(encode_special_chars: false)
 => "test <script>alert('hacked!')</script>"
```

So they're also a no go

Comment: Can you give an example of the string in question and the result you want?

Comment: I've updated with the real world example

Answer (score 2):

You have to parse the HTML and extract the text elements. Use Nokogiri to do that.

```
Nokogiri::HTML("<div>Strip <i>this</i> & <b>this</b> & <u>this</u>!</div>").text
```

Nokogiri is already used by Rails so there's no cost to using it.

---

You will get all the text, including the content of `<script>` tags.

```
Nokogiri::HTML(%q[test<script>alert('hacked!');</script>&test]).text

# testalert('hacked!');&test
```

You can strip the `<script>` tags.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(%q[test<script>alert('hacked!');</script>&test])
doc.search('//script').each { |node| node.replace('') }
doc.text

# test&test
```

But with the tags stripped out the string is of no harm. It might not be worth the effort.

See the [Nokogiri tutorials](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/toc.html) for more.

Comment: Oh, that what exactly I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Ah, no sorry, it won't work :(
See my update at the bottom of the question

Comment: @HandsomeJack What is your ultimate outcome? Are you protecting against HTML injection? Or are you extracting text from HTML? It seems like both. Those are different. If both, extract the text and then escape any HTML which might have been lurking in the text. But you should already be escaping your text before you use it, not when you save it; that way you're not guessing how it will be used. Extract the text, store it in the database. Then you can use it for anything. Then escape *any* text before you put it into HTML, don't assume it's already escaped.